# How to pass text from console to text editor

Tags: java, console

I am developing a spelling correction program using Java. I am using the JNativeHook library to listen to global keyboard events and then produce the corrected word for the input. However, I am not able to pass this content to the window in focus (text area).

Is there any way through which I can pass my text from the console to another application (Browser, Text Editor, etc.)?

- OS: Linux
- IDE: Eclipse

Comment: Your program has console and Applet/Swing front-end and you want to pass data typed on console to your textarea or another place, is that right?

Comment: Yes. My application reads input automatically and the Swing Window setAlwaysOnTop property is set to true. I need to pass text from my Swing/Console to another application. Specifically, the application that is in focus.

Comment: So you have two applications running at the same time or just once with multiple GUIs?

Comment: Since I am trying to develop a spelling correction application, I have designed it to run on top of other applications. Its purpose is to correct misspellings entered by the user in other applications. My application reads keyboard inputs while the user types, and returns the corrected word. I need to pass this corrected word to the application in focus. My application consists of just one GUI. I need to pass this corrected word to a third party software (Browser, Notepad, etc.).